# Same http request to multiple web servers

Tags: http

Is there any way to forward same http request to multiple web servers ?

For example. I have server1 and it has one web application running on 80 port .The same application is running on server2 on same port i.e 80.

Is it possible to get the same request on both the servers with some time lag ?.

Please help.Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: This sounds a bit suspicious. What would you need that for?

Comment: I want to divert the same request to my test server which is also performing the same activities as the prod server.I want to see the behaviour of the test server after i have changed a few services from python to java